# Write in body request with HttpClient

Tags: java, xml, request, apache-httpclient-4.x

I want to write the body of a request with XML content-type but I don't know how with HttpClient Object ( http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/index.html )

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpRequest = new HttpPost(this.url);
httpRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
```

And I don't know how to continue to write the body with my XML ...

Answer (score 123, accepted):

If your xml is written by `java.lang.String` you can just using `HttpClient` in this way

```
    public void post() throws Exception{
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.baidu.com");
        String xml = "<xml>xxxx</xml>";
        HttpEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(xml.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        post.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    }
```

pay attention to the Exceptions.

BTW, the example is written by the httpclient version 4.x

Comment: I would suggest using `java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets`, and modify the `ByteArrayEntity` line into:

    HttpEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(xml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

Comment: Instead of `new ByteArrayEntity(xml.getBytes("UTF-8"));` use `new StringEntity(xml, ContentType.APPLICATION_XML);`

Comment: Using new StringEntity may result in the incorrect charset declared in the header. Use with care.

Comment: Should use [HttpClientBuilder.create().build()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32372938) instead since `DefaultHttpClient` is deprecated.

Comment: I am hitting an endpoint that is created by me only on another Spring boot application and it is a post method but it is giving error as request body not found. I implemented the answer. I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 28):

Extending your code (assuming that the XML you want to send is in `xmlString`) :

```
String xmlString = "</xml>";
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpRequest = new HttpPost(this.url);
httpRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
StringEntity xmlEntity = new StringEntity(xmlString);
httpRequest.setEntity(xmlEntity );
HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```